# Spatial functions with MySQL, XAMPP, and Wordpress

Tags: leaflet, php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to figure out how to using the ST_AsGeoJSON function in MySQL, but I keep getting an error that says that this function does not exist. I have found in the MySQL documentation that this spatial function does exist.

```
mysql> SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(11.11111 12.22222)'),2);
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-geojson-functions.html

My current setup is Windows 10 with XAMPP with Wordpress.

Comment: What's your exact MySQL version? (should be somewhere in the XAMPP documentation for your particular installation, or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987679/how-to-retrieve-the-current-version-of-a-mysql-database )

Comment: Thanks for responding. My version is 10.1.32-MariaDB. I just did some research and learned that this function is not supported in MariaDB until version 10.2. I will try to upgrade my db to see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that MariaDB did not begin supporting spatial functions until version 10.2. To resolve my issue I simply upgraded my version of MariaDB from 10.1.32 to version 10.3. This however, took quite a bit of configuration to get XAMPP and PhpMyAdmin to perform correctly.

MariaDB upgrade:
https://medium.com/@meness/steps-to-upgrade-mariadb-for-xampp-7924326731d3

**I did not perform the last step, but everything worked
***You may have to configure various credentials within phpmyadmin config files

After performing the upgrade, I was able to display markers on within Wordpress on a leaflet map.